# Prove that monotonic function defined on a measurable set is continuous almost everywhere

Tags: continuity, monotone-functions, measurable-functions

*Theorem:*  **If a function f defined on a measurable set D ⊂ R is continuous almost everywhere then f is measurable.**

*Corollary:*  **Monotonic functions defined on measurable sets are measurable.**

The corollary was given as corollary of the above theorem. That means any monotonic function defined on a measurable set is continuous almost everywhere.

I saw the proofs with domain as intervals only. But here the domain is measurable which is larger class containing intervals. How to prove that monotonic function defined on a measurable set will not be continuous on a measurable set with measure 0 only?
Any help will be of great help!

Comment: At isolated points any function is continuous. At limit points of the domain use the same argument as the one for $\mathbb  R$ as the domain. Right-hand limit and left -hand limits are equal except at countably many points.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [continuity of monotonically increasing function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2277653/continuity-of-monotonically-increasing-function)